# Cast a nativeElement into a DebugElement in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

i was tesing an Angular Component and everything was going well until i ran into a problem that i've been trying to solve for days now. All i wanted to do is test if the method "ajouterCompteurALaCampagne" is called when inserting a row, so i tried to access the dx-data-grid DOM element so i can emit the event "onRowInserting", and this is where the problem occured, i cannot access that element as a DebugElement but only as a nativeElement. Therefore i cannot emit the onRowInserting event and see if the method was called or not. So my question is: "can i do a sort of casting to the nativeElement so i can have access to the DebugElement properties?"

***HTML CODE***

```
<dx-tab-panel
  [height]="'auto'"
  [dataSource]="tabs"
  [selectedIndex]="0"
  [loop]="false"
  [animationEnabled]="true">

 
  <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'compteursTemplate'">
    <dx-data-grid
      #tabCompteurCampagne
      id = 'liste-compteur'
      [showBorders]="true"
      [dataSource]="listeCompteur"
      (onRowInserting)="ajouterCompteurALaCampagne($event)"
      (onRowRemoving)="supprimerCompteurCampagne($event)"
      (onRowUpdated)="modifierCompteurCampagne($event)">
    ...</dx-data-grid>
  ...</div>
...<dx-tab-panel>
```

***TYPESCRIPT CODE***

```
it("should call the method 'ajouterCompteurALaCampagne' once the event is emitted", async(()=>{
  let spy_ajouterCompteurALaCampagne = spyOn(component, "ajouterCompteurALaCampagne");
  let dxTabPanelElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.directive(DxTabPanelComponent)
  );
 let dxGridElement = dxTabPanelElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#liste-compteur');
  dxGridElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("rowInserting")); //the event is not emmited
  expect(spy_ajouterCompteurALaCampagne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));
 });
```

Comment: dx-data-grid is an custom component? You are mocking It ir using the real one in test?

Comment: The project uses a Javascript UI components library for Angular called DevExtreme, that's where the dx-data-grid component comes from. For the testing, i included the devextreme module in the imports array of the TestBed. I use the real dx-data-grid not a mock, i'm only mocking the service and the component. Hope i made it clear.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to this problem, thank u for your answers guys.
Here is the code:

```
it("should call the method 'ajouterCompteurALaCampagne' once the event is emitted", async(()=>{
let spy_ajouterCompteurALaCampagne = spyOn(component, "ajouterCompteurALaCampagne");
let dxGridElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector("dx-data-grid");
console.log(dxGridElement);
dxGridElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("onRowInserting"));
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(spy_ajouterCompteurALaCampagne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

}));

I hope this helps somebody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a `debugElement`? In these kinds of situations, I think you can use `triggerEventHandler` and I think it comes from Angular.

Try this:

```
it("should call the method 'ajouterCompteurALaCampagne' once the event is emitted", async(()=>{
  let spy_ajouterCompteurALaCampagne = spyOn(component, "ajouterCompteurALaCampagne");
  // use fixture.
  let dxGridElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('dx-data-grid'));
  dxGridElement.triggerEventHandler('onRowInserting', { /* here you can mock the $event object */ });
  expect(spy_ajouterCompteurALaCampagne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```

Comment: Hello @AliF50, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately i already tried that, but it didn't work, it gives this error: "Property 'debugEelement' does not exist on type 'DebugEelement'".                                                                                                                 The element "dxTabPanel" is of type DebugElement, consequently we cannot use the debugEelement property on it.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Instead of `dxTabPanelElement.`, use `fixture.` That should work IMO. Always use `fixture.` when querying. I have edited my answer two show `fixture.`

Comment: Well that's the first problem i encountered, i tired to that in the first place and access the dxDataGrid Element directly from the fixture but it renders me null.

Comment: To see the whole DOM, you can do `console.log(fixture.nativeElement)` and then you can try to do inserting of a row manually by clicking the plus icon. I assume clicking the plus icon in the data-grid component will trigger onRowInserting.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, i've found a solution to my problem.                                                    So basically what i have done, is access the dx-data-grid as a native element, and after that i dispatched the "onRowInserting" event and it worked.                                                I already did that before, there was a litlle problem with my code, instead of dispatching a "onRowInserting" event, i dispatched a "rowInsertingEvent", consequently the method was not called. Thanks a lot again my friend.